# Best way(s) to time ad hoc queries and stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, performance

What are the most accepted ways to time your queries, whether they are ad hoc or stored procedures?

Is it more accurate to use **SQL Profiler** than `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In either case you are getting the run time from the server, so you should get the same values from either.

Comment: +1 as Set Statistics time on **will** report timing issues from black box udfs (http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/04/29/functions-io-statistics-and-the-execution-plan/)

Comment: We are looking at run time here which is included in both.  Things like IO and CPU load aren't accounted for but run time is as the counter starts when the command starts and finishes when it is done.

Answer (score 4):

Profiler is easier to understand (all in one line) and will capture hidden IO, CPU etc in UDFs (scalar and multi-statement TVFs)

<strike>SET STATISTICS TIME ON</strike> and SET STATISTICS IO ON *will not* show you IO and CPU from scalar UDFs and multi-statement TVFs: only the "outer" query statistics

From SO:

- [SQL Server Profiler discrepancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031959/sql-server-profiler-discrepancy/1031983#1031983)
- [Table Valued Function where did my query plan go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432343/table-valued-function-where-did-my-query-plan-go/1432413#1432413)
- [Does query plan optimizer works well with joined/filtered table-valued functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311026/does-query-plan-optimizer-works-well-with-joined-filtered-table-valued-functions/311163#311163)

And no doubt some folk will disagree with me, so here is Adam Machanic on the subject too

- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)

Comment: +1 as good points on scalar functions and how set statistics io on doesn't report them (didn't know, thanks!), however set statitistics **time** will show you the total time taken (just not be easily explained by set statistics profile/io)

Comment: @Andrew Bickerton: I rarely use CPU time: mostly IOs so had forgotten/overlooked. And I avoid udfs with table access too where I can

Comment: @gbn that last link you posted, I don't understand why a TVF is much more efficient then a scalar UDF.  To me that is not intuitive.  Why would it be THAT much more hits for a scalar UDF??

Comment: @Surfer513: there are 2 kinds of TVF and one scalr. The UDFs with BEGIN..END must run to completion. The inline TVFs expand into the outer query